# want to print answer if q is answered incorrectly, and give two more chances

Tags: python

So I have an assessment due tomorrow (it is all finished) and was hoping to add a few more details in.
How would I:
a. Make it so that if you answer the question wrong, you can retry twice
b. if you completely fail, you get shown the answer
How would i do this? thanks
ps. The code lloks retarded, i couldn't get it in

```
}  output = " "  score = 0   print('Hello, and welcome to my quiz on Ed Sheeran!')  for question_number,question in enumerate(questions):  print ("Question",question_number+1) 
print (question)
for options in questions[question][:-1]: 
    print (options)
user_choice = input("Make your choice : ")
if user_choice == questions[question][-1]: 
    print ("Correct!")
    score += 1
    print (score)
    print (output)

else: 
    print ("Wrong!")
    print (score)
    print (output)

   print(score)
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have understood from your query is that you want user to input the option twice before we move to the next question.
Also you want to display the answer if the user has incorrectly answered in both the chances.

I don't know how your questions and answers are stored but you can use the below code as a pseudo code.

The below code should work:

```
print('Hello, and welcome to my quiz on Ed Sheeran!')
for question_number,question in enumerate(questions):
    print ("Question",question_number+1) 
    print (question)
    tmp = 0
    for options in questions[question][:-1]: 
        print (options)
    for j in range(2):
        user_choice = input("Make your choice : ")
        if user_choice == questions[question][-1]: 
            print ("Correct!")
            score += 1
            break
        else: 
            print ("Wrong!")
            tmp += 1
            if tmp == 2:
                print ('You got it wrong, Correct answer is: ' output)
    print(score)
```

Comment: Hi,most of this works, but im still getting an error of 'no value for (output)', which i was hoping to display the answer. What do i put here in: output = ?. Thanks for mopst of it though

Comment: does your 'answer' is in 'questions' or is it in some other variable?